# How to skip a block in Java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, breakpoints

In the program given I have to make sure that if two consequtive characters are the same. I shouldn't increase the value of the variable (Count)... I have tried "break;", but that skips me out of the "for loop" which is very counter-productive. How can I skip the given part and still continue the "for loop"?

Currently my output for "Hello//world" is 3. It should be 2 (the '/' indicates a ' '(Space)).

#### Code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class CountWordsWithEmergency
{
    public static void main()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input the String");
        String inp = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("thank you");
        int i = inp.length();
        int count = 1;
        for(int j=0;j<=i-1;j++) //This is the for loop I would like to stay in.
        {
            char check = inp.charAt(j);
            if(check==' ')
            {
                if((inp.charAt(j+1))==check) //This is the condition to prevent increase for
                                             //count variable.
                {
                    count = count; //This does not work and neither does break;
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The number of words are : "+count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the keyword `continue` in order to accomplish what you are trying to do.

However you can also inverse your conditional test and use `count++` only if it is different (`!=` instead of `==` in your if) and do nothing otherwise

Comment: Ok so your solution is this..good explained. no one other having explanation that the reason your answer is good.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ((inp.charAt(j+1)) != check)  {
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The word you are looking for is "[continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/801hyx6f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)".

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if ((inp.charAt(j+1)) != check)  {
    count++;
}
```

Increment the value of count by checking with `!=`.

Comment: `!=` is a comparison, not an increment.

Answer (score 1):

Try using continue where you want to skip an block.

Answer (score 1):

Use "[continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/801hyx6f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx);" when you want to break the current iteration.

Answer (score 1):

continue is a keyword in java programming used to skip the loop or block of code and reexecutes the loop with new condition.

continue statement is used only in while,do while and for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class CountWordsWithEmergency
{
    public static void main()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input the String");
        String inp = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("thank you");
        int i = inp.length();
        int count = 1;
        for(int j=0;j<=i-1;j++) //This is the for loop I would like to stay in.
        {
            char check = inp.charAt(j);
            if(check==' ')
            {
                if((inp.charAt(j+1))==check) //This is the condition to prevent increase for
                                             //count variable.
                {
                    continue;
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The number of words are : "+count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the `continue` keyword, or modify the logic a little bit:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class CountWordsWithEmergency  
{
  public static void main()
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input the String");
    String inp = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("thank you");
    int i = inp.length();
    int count = 1;
    for(int j=0;j<=i-1;j++) //This is the for loop I would like to stay in.
    {
      char check = inp.charAt(j);
      if(check==' ')
      {
        if((inp.charAt(j+1))!=check)
        {
          count++;
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println("The number of words are : "+count);
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

You may want to use the `split` method of the `String` class.

```
int wordsCount = str.split(' ').length;
```

Hope it helps :)